# onclick function in vue does not render my custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and i want to render a component after a user clicks on a button. Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly?

The `<sample-component>` is just a banner that's meant to appear at the top of the page

Sample Code

```
<template>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <sample-button @click="showBanner">
                Show banner
            </simplex-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        showBanner() {
            return `
            <template id="banner">
                <div class="banner-page">
                    <sample-component>
                        <p> hello </p>
                    </sample-component>
                </div>
            </template>`;          
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<template>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <sample-button @click="showBanner()">
                Show banner
            </sample-button>
            <div id="banner" v-if="visible">
                <div class="banner-page">
                    <sample-component>
                        <p> hello </p>
                    </sample-component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showBanner() {
            this.visible = true        
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

You just can render it by changing a `data` property which passed into `v-if` directive

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you shouldn't be returning the template from the method and also you cannot assign an `id` to a `<template>` tag since they don't actually get rendered. So you basically need to change your template to below:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="content">
      <!-- note that your banner component has shifted here -->
      <div v-if="isBannerVisible" id="banner">
        <div class="banner-page">
          <sample-component>
            <p>hello</p>
          </sample-component>
        </div>
      </div>

      <sample-button @click="isBannerVisible = true">
        Show banner
      </sample-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and your script as well to:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

// since your using Typescript it is better to use the class syntax
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  private isBannerVisible: boolean = false
};
</script>
```